# how to solve the problem of creating multiple static pages

Tags: php, mysql, html, static

i am working on a site where i need to retrive data from a single table and display some of the data as pages.

for example:

```
name: xyz
state: Texas
city: Dallas
category: test
```

etc... I have no.of records like this in a table. what i need is to retrieve all the states in one page and all the cities as one page and all the categories as one page making a relation between them. When i'm on states page if i click on texas all the related cities has to be displayed in another page. When i'm on category page if i click on a category i need to display all the states that relates to that category.

All this can be done using queries but, what i want is to display them as static pages. So, can you please suggest me a solution for this?

Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have -any- code to provide us to work with? This really seems like a "here's what I want, give me some code" question.

Comment: Do you need static pages or do you need URL that looks like static page?

Answer (score 1):

Why do they have to be static?

If it's a performance thing, you can generate them dynamically and cache the results. If it's a server limitation (cost, security, etc), then generate them locally, and copy that over to the server. If it's the age-old 'static pages are better for SEO' thing then that doesn't apply any more, and you can just add .html to the URL with Apache.